# Sql 2008 Restoring a backed up DB fails - what else can i do?

Tags: sql-server, backup

i'm trying to restore our live DB onto our Dev box. To do this, I when onto production, TASKS -> backup Db. it created a 4Gig file. I zipped this down to 2.2Gig. download that to my dev server.

On my dev server, i create a new DB (called 'xxxxx') and then Tasks -> restore DB from file. I give it the .bak file name, overwrite all and go.

When it gets to 40% it fails. here's the screenie:

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/1/restorefailurejl5.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/1/restorefailurejl5.png)

Now, i can manually zip up the .mdf and .log files, zip them, download them and then attach them to my dev server sql instance. I did that last night actually, to get this working .. so that worked.

But i'm not sure why the backup/restore method didn't work? I've downloaded the .bak file a few times (in case the download was corrupt). i tried to rezip and re-backup the live server a few times also .. but after about the 5 download of a 2Gig file, I'm starting to get grumpy :)

I've tried doing a `DBCC CHECKDB('live db name', RESTORE_REBUILD)` and that worked fine and THEN backup, download, restore, fail.

My live DB is sql2008 x64bit and my dev box is x86 (32 bit), so i'm not sure if that's an issue. Both servers are *versions 10.0 RTM*.

I don't want to have to stop the db to be able to copy the .mdf/.log files (cause u can't access them while the db is running, i believe) .. which is why i prefer the backup/restore method.

Any suggestions?

### UPDATE 1

Before i posted this question, I did do a DBCC CHECKDB ('xxxxx', RESTORE_REBUILD). I noted this in my initial post, which i've now just highlighted for future reference.

When i get a chance to stop the DB, i'll post the end results here (and save the text output incase someone asks for some other info).

### UPDATE 2

I tried to restore the backup to a dummy live db i created. Failed (same error message). I'm running a DBCC CHECKDB('LiveDB') right now. Just before I did this, i stopped the SQL Server *service* & manually copy-backedup the .mdb and .log files.

### UPDATE 3

This is the result from the DBCC CHECKDB ('LiveDb')

> DBCC results
>   for 'Addresses' There are 1689363 rows
>   in 101624 pages for object 'Addresses'
>   DBCC results for 'Thumbnails' There
>   are 1197 rows in 30 pages for object
>   'Thumbnails'  ..
>   CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and
>   0 consistency errors in database
>   'LiveDb' DBCC execution completed. If
>   DBCC printed error messages, contact
>   your administrator.

hmm :( Any further ideas? Should i run DBCC again with RESTORE_REBUILD or some other magic argument?

### Final Update

Ok - this is sooo weird. After running CHECK DBCC and then doing another full backup (using the same sql script that we have been using for eons) the restore now works fine! I just don't get it :(

Looks like i can close the job now. I just don't get it :(

Comment: did you run DBCC CHECKDB recently?

Comment: Yep. it worked fine as far as i could tell. I can't remember if there was some fragmentation but there was lots of text it outputted. i'll try it one more time and display the results.

Comment: Performing a backup on a 64bit system and then restoring to a 32bit system is a common practice and so unlikely to be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Also are you restoring to a SQL 2008 Server that is running the same build version as your production server?

Comment: v 10.0 RTM. Also, i've updated the main post. Thanks for the help John :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is IMPORTANT, you may potentially have an issue with the live database.

Have you performed DBCC CHECKDB on your production server recently? If not, do so at the next possible maintenance window.

You should ideally be performing CHECKDB before you take your full backups (although not always practical) in order to validate that the backups you are generating, are of a database that has been confirmed to be without issue.

Please feel free to pose further questions. You can contact me directly if you require additional assistance.

Cheers, John

Comment: Just running the command ( DBCC CHECKDB('LiveDB') )on the live db (after i did a manual copy of the mdb and log files with the service stopped) .. hope this works!

Comment: Updated inital post with more info.

Comment: John, after i ran DBCC CHECKDB('LiveDB') and then tried a restore .. it worked. Does DBCC CHECKDB do anything, regardless of finding errors or not? or is it purely a thing that CHECKS for problems?

Comment: Given that DBCC CheckDB has not produced any error messages, it would appear that your production database is in working order. The source of your issue is likely elsewhere. See my latest comment added to your question.

Answer (score 0):

We do the same thing every morning.

```
RESTORE DATABASE Accounts FROM DISK = '\\server\F$\SQL_BACKUP\DB.bak' WITH REPLACE
```

This works fine for us.  I'm not sure if the x64 > x32 will have an impact, I wasn't aware that data was stored differently between those kinds of platforms.  We basically dump our live database every night, a process on our SQL server then picks them up, and another process sends them to be backed up to disk.

The command above will create you a new database and import the data, it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your production database has some corruption.  Run DBCC CHECKDB on your production database and see what is returned.

Comment: yep - just did this and it failed. running the DBCC CheckDB right now.

Comment: Updated inital post with more info.

Comment: Did checkdb tell you anything when you ran it?  (If you still happen to have the output).

Answer (score 0):

Does a restore on the live machine (to a different db) fail? If so, try running DBCC CHECKDB.

Comment: It failed on the Live machine also. What i did => task->backup live. Create new db. Restore back to this new (dummy) db. Same failure message. I'm running a DBCC CHECKDB('LiveDB') now....

Comment: Updated inital post with more info.